# ASP.NET using C#, auto refresh div in a Repeater

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use a Repeater control to list the threads.

And there is a Div with a Label control for displaying the posted date in Repeater ItemTemplate.

here is what I'm doing now, but it's not auto refresh specific div independently. It's auto refresh the whole page.

```
setInterval(function () { $(".refresh").load(location.href + " .refresh"); }, 5000);


<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
      <HeaderTemplate>

      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
            ..........
            .............

          <div class="date"><asp:Label ID="post_date_LB" runat="server"></asp:Label></div> 
            //display the posted date for each thread, And I want it to auto refresh independently not the whole page.

          ...............
          ...................

      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>

      </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want the posted date display something like this: posted 10 minutes ago, an hour age, etc.

so I need a auto refresh div.

Is there any idea how to let my div in a repeater could auto refresh independently?

If using js or jquery, I think there might be a issue with DIV duplicate id.

Hope there is a solution for this.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX.

You can put the part need refreshing independently inside the UpdatePanel control. You will also need to use one script manager control.

It is in your AJAX toolbox.

Comment: Search google for UpdatePanel you will have pretty good tutorials also you should be able to find video's on Youtube too.

Answer (score 0):

It is also best Idea to use ajax updatepanel with timer.

But if you want to using jQuery and AJAX, this may be this code helpful for you

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
          <HeaderTemplate>

          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
                ..........
                .............

              <div class="date"><%-- <asp:Label ID="post_date_LB" runat="server"></asp:Label> --%> 
<div class="refresh" data-postid="<%= Eval("PostIDColumn")%>"><%= defaultTime(Eval("Postcreated")) %></div> <%-- Create method to count time defaultTime--%>
</div> 
                //display the posted date for each thread, And I want it to auto refresh independently not the whole page.

              ...............
              ...................

          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>

          </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Now in JavaScript using jQuery

```
setInterval(function () { $(".refresh").load(location.href + " .refresh"); }, 5000);
```

instead of above line

```
setInterval(/*It will loop and get the new time from server*/function () { $(".refresh").each(function(){
$(this).load("ajax.aspx",{postid:function(){return $(this).data('postid');}});
}); }, 5000);
```

And Finlay my suggestion is, if it just showing time line then don't use AJAX call. you can do this in client side script (javascript) itself.

```
setInterval(/*It will loop and get the new time from server*/
    function () { $(".refresh").each(function(){
        var current= $(this);
        var time=current.data('postedDateTime');
        current.html((collectTime(time) );
            }); }, 5000);
```

Comment: thanks for your time here. :) but I tested ur code, it didn't work for me. It seems your jquery code has partially incorrect. =>  ......each.............).....

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, now I changed it. I forget to put dot before each.... And also it is just for an idea. I did not run code.. What about changing time in client side itself?

Comment: It's okay, would like to try changing time in client side itself. this problem suffer me for months. ><!

Comment: Thats best change in client side.. it is best too, unless your not doing like bidding things in your site (where we need more secure). All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update the date, but not gather any additional data i would suggest calculating the passed time on the client.

Once the initial posted date got send to the client you can update the user friendly time info ("just now", "five minutes ago", "yesterday" etc.) via javascript. That way you save bandwith and cpu on the server.